# How to process RDDs using a Python class?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm implementing a model in Spark as a python class, and any time I try to map a class method to an RDD it fails. My actual code is more complicated, but this simplified version gets at the heart of the problem:

```
class model(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = sc.textFile('path/to/data.csv')
        # other misc setup
    def run_model(self):
        self.data = self.data.map(self.transformation_function)
    def transformation_function(self,row):
        row = row.split(',')
        return row[0]+row[1]
```

Now, if I run the model like so (for example):

```
test = model()
test.run_model()
test.data.take(10)
```

I get the following error:

Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transforamtion. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.

I've played with this a bit, and it seems to reliably occur anytime I try to map a class method to an RDD within the class. I have confirmed that the mapped function works fine if I implement outside of a class structure, so the problem definitely has to do with the class. Is there a way to resolve this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Problem here is a little bit more subtle than using *nested RDDs or performing Spark actions inside of transformations*. Spark doesn't allow access to the `SparkContext` inside action or transformation.

Even you don't access it explicitly it is referenced inside the closure and has to be serialized and carried around. It means that your `transformation` method, which references `self`, keeps `SparkContext` as well, hence the error.

One way to handle this is to use static method:

```
class model(object):
    @staticmethod
    def transformation_function(row):
        row = row.split(',')
        return row[0]+row[1]

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = sc.textFile('some.csv')

    def run_model(self):
        self.data = self.data.map(model.transformation_function)
```

**Edit**:

If you want to be able to access instance variables you can try something like this:

```
class model(object):
    @staticmethod
    def transformation_function(a_model):
        delim = a_model.delim
        def _transformation_function(row):
            return row.split(delim)
        return _transformation_function

    def __init__(self):
        self.delim = ','
        self.data = sc.textFile('some.csv')

    def run_model(self):
        self.data = self.data.map(model.transformation_function(self))
```

Comment: Perfect - I didn't think of using a static method. Only issue is in the full code, my transform function needs to access other variables in the `model` class (not RDDs). I'm assuming the only way to achieve that is to pass them as arguments to the static method? e.g. `def transformation_function(row,somevar): return row+somevar`

Comment: In other words - is there a way to access class variables (`self.whatever`) from within a static method?

Comment: (note that these can't be static variables - I would definitely want to access instance variables from within the static method)

Comment: If I it was possible you would face exactly the same issue. One thing you can do is return function from a static method.

Comment: Why does it have to be a static function? Why not `def transformation_function(self):...` ? Is it because it won't work when you pass it to an rdd, even if it is essentially static?

Comment: Because `transformation_function` is not "essentially static".  It captures `self` in its scope, and transitively `RDD` object and `SparkContext`.