# Proper handling of spark broadcast variables in a Python class

Tags: python, apache-spark

I've been implementing a model with spark via a python class. I had some headaches calling class methods on a RDD defined in the class (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32505426/how-to-process-rdds-using-a-python-class/) for details), but finally have made some progress. Here is an example of a class method I'm working with:

```
@staticmethod
def alpha_sampler(model):

    # all the variables in this block are numpy arrays or floats
    var_alpha = model.params.var_alpha
    var_rating = model.params.var_rating
    b = model.params.b
    beta = model.params.beta
    S = model.params.S
    Z = model.params.Z
    x_user_g0_inner_over_var = model.x_user_g0_inner_over_var

    def _alpha_sampler(row):
        feature_arr = row[2]
        var_alpha_given_rest = 1/((1/var_alpha) + feature_arr.shape[0]*(1/var_rating))
        i = row[0]
        items = row[1]
        O = row[3] - np.inner(feature_arr,b) - beta[items] - np.inner(S[i],Z[items])
        E_alpha_given_rest = var_alpha_given_rest * (x_user_g0_inner_over_var[i] + O.sum()/var_rating)
        return np.random.normal(E_alpha_given_rest,np.sqrt(var_alpha_given_rest))
    return _alpha_sampler
```

As you can see, to avoid serialization errors, I define a static method that returns a function that is in turn applied to each row of an RDD (`model` is the parent class here, and this is called from within another method of `model`):

```
# self.grp_user is the RDD
self.params.alpha = np.array(self.grp_user.map(model.alpha_sampler(self)).collect())
```

Now, this all works fine, but is not leveraging Spark's broadcast variables at all. Ideally, all the variables I'm passing in this function (var_alpha, beta, S, etc.) could first be broadcast to the workers, so that I wasn't redundantly passing them as part of the `map`. But I'm not sure how to do this.

My question, then, is the following: How/where should I make these into broadcast variables such that they are available to the `alpha_sampler` function that I map to `grp_user`? One thing I believe will work would be to make them globals, e.g.

```
global var_alpha
var_alpha = sc.broadcast(model.params.var_alpha)
# and similarly for the other variables...
```

Then the alpha_sampler could be much simplified:

```
@staticmethod
def _alpha_sampler(row):
    feature_arr = row[2]
    var_alpha_given_rest = 1/((1/var_alpha.value) + feature_arr.shape[0]*(1/var_rating.value))
    i = row[0]
    items = row[1]
    O = row[3] - np.inner(feature_arr,b.value) - beta.value[items] - np.inner(S.value[i],Z.value[items])
    E_alpha_given_rest = var_alpha_given_rest * (x_user_g0_inner_over_var.value[i] + O.sum()/var_rating.value)
    return np.random.normal(E_alpha_given_rest,np.sqrt(var_alpha_given_rest))
```

But of course this is really dangerous use of globals that I would like to avoid. Is there a better way that lets me leverage broadcast variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that variables you use here are simply scalars there is probably nothing to gain here from a performance perspective and using broadcast variables will make you code less readable but you can either pass a broadcast variable as an argument to the static method:

```
class model(object):
    @staticmethod
    def foobar(a_model, mu):
        y = a_model.y
        def _foobar(x):
            return x - mu.value + y 
        return _foobar

    def __init__(self, sc):
        self.sc = sc
        self.y = -1
        self.rdd = self.sc.parallelize([1, 2, 3])

    def get_mean(self):
        return self.rdd.mean()

    def run_foobar(self):
        mu = self.sc.broadcast(self.get_mean())
        self.data = self.rdd.map(model.foobar(self, mu))
```

or initialize it there:

```
class model(object):
    @staticmethod
    def foobar(a_model):
        mu = a_model.sc.broadcast(a_model.get_mean())
        y = a_model.y
        def _foobar(x):
            return x - mu.value + y 
        return _foobar

    def __init__(self, sc):
        self.sc = sc
        self.y = -1
        self.rdd = self.sc.parallelize([1, 2, 3])

    def get_mean(self):
        return self.rdd.mean()

    def run_foobar(self):
        self.data = self.rdd.map(model.foobar(self))
```