# Registering spark SQL User Defined Function within a Python class

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm doing some data processing with Spark via the Python API. Here's a simplified bit of the class I'm working with:

```
class data_processor(object):
    def __init__(self,filepath):
        self.config = Config() # this loads some config options from file
        self.type_conversions = {int:IntegerType,str:StringType}
        self.load_data(filepath)
        self.format_age()

    def load_data(self,filepath,delim='\x01'):
        cols = [...] # list of column names 
        types = [int, str, str, ... ] # list of column types
        user_data = sc.textFile(filepath,use_unicode=False).map(lambda row: [types[i](val) for i,val in enumerate(row.strip().split(delim))])
        fields = StructType([StructField(field_name,self.type_conversions[field_type]()) for field_name,field_type in zip(cols,types)])
        self.user_data = user_data.toDF(fields)
        self.user_data.registerTempTable('data')

    def format_age(self):
        age_range = self.config.age_range # tuple of (age_min, age_max)
        age_bins = self.config.age_bins # list of bin boundaries
        def _format_age(age):
            if age<age_range[0] or age>age_range[1]:
                return None
            else:
                return  np.digitize([age],age_bins)[0]
        sqlContext.udf.register('format_age', lambda x: _format_age(x), IntegerType())
```

Now, if I instantiate the class with `data=data_processor(filepath)`, I can do queries on the dataframe just fine. This, for examples, works:

```
sqlContext.sql("select * from data limit 10").take(1)
```

But I'm clearly not setting up the udf properly. If I try, for instance,

```
sqlContext.sql("select age, format_age(age) from data limit 10").take(1)
```

I get an error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
```

(with a long stacktrace, typical of Spark, that's too long to include here).

So, what am I doing wrong exactly? What is the proper way to define a UDF within a method like this (preferably as a class method). I know Spark doesn't like passing class objects, hence the nested structure of `format_age` (inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32569241/proper-handling-of-spark-broadcast-variables-in-a-python-class/32569955#32569955)).

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is  short and simple. You cannot use NumPy data types as a drop-in replacement for standard Python types in Spark SQL. Returned type of `np.digitize` is a `numpy.int64` not an `int` expected when you declare a return type as an `IntegerType`.

All you have to do is cast a value returned from `_format_age`:

```
def _format_age(age):
    ...
    return  int(np.digitize(...))
```