# Can't Pickle Thread Lock Object

Tags: python, apache-spark, logging, pyspark, pickle

I am trying to run the following code in python:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf  
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark import SparkConf
import pyspark.sql.functions as pf
import logging
import sys

from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

log = logging.getLogger('EXT')

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def ext_udf(self, f):
        return udf(lambda f: self.test(1))
    def test(self,arg):
        return(arg)



    def create_df(self):
        log.info("Test")
        log.debug("Test")
        conf = SparkConf().setAppName('Extr')
        sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
        sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
        df = SQLContext.createDataFrame(sqlContext,[{'name': 'Alice', 'age': 1}])
        df.withColumn('meta-data', self.ext_udf(1)(pf.col("name"))).show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.INFO)
    t=Test()
    t.create_df()
```

I know, it doesn't make sense at all, but it does reproduce my error.

```
    Could not pickle thread lock
```

or something like that.

By now I found out, that it has to do with the logging object and with the call of a self method in extraction_udf() . When I remove the logging it will work and when I use a non object function instead of self.test() it will also work.

Do you have any Ideas on how to solve this, or can explain, why this is happening?

I don't know why the link disappeared, but I think I will try this post here:
[How to process RDDs using a Python class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32505426/how-to-process-rdds-using-a-python-class)

Though my problem seems different, as it will work, as long as I don't involve the logging.