# Passing python class objects in Pyspark Rdd map function

Tags: python, serialization, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

While executing the below code where I pass python class object to pyspark rdd map function and got below error:
PicklingError: could not serialize object: TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects

I also tried converting it to static method but still the issue is same.
[How to process RDDs using a Python class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32505426/how-to-process-rdds-using-a-python-class)

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
import logging

class test(object):
    def __init__(self, sc, logger):
        logger.info('Ind=side init method.')
        data = sc.parallelize([1,2,3,4])
        data.foreach(lambda x: test.log_data(x, logger))

    @staticmethod
    def log_data(data, logger):
        logger.info(data)


conf = SparkConf().setAppName('test')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

test(sc, logger)
```